A rule involves Pattern, Times and Optional works in version 8, but not in version 14
Bug introduced in 11.0, persisting through 14.1.


Background info
I enocountered this problem when exploring
Pattern match about Times default value
But this turns out to be a different issue i.e. the behavior of code
sample in the link is consistent in version 8 and version 14. So I
decide to post this as a separate question.

Consider this example:
Replace[x y, c_. (a : (x y)) :> aaa]

In version 8.0.4, the output is aaa, which looks reasonable for me:

But it's not the case in version 14.1:

I don't have access to version 9 to 13 at the moment so cannot do further test.
My question is:

Is this a bug, or intentional incompatible change (this does happen in the past, see e.g. this and this)?

If it's an intentional change, what's the underlying reason for it?



Version 13.3 also returns x y.

To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my question, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want to improve my question if possible.

Version 12.0.1 also returns x y

It appears to have changed in version 11.0. I do not yet know the cause.

This returns x y  in Version "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)". Note that this only seems to be a problem for multiplication: Both Replace[x + y, c_. (a : (x + y)) :> aaa] and Replace[f[x, y], c_. (a : f[x, y]) :> aaa] yield aaa, so I wonder if this is doing some multiplication simplification first or something like that.

It's worth noting that the matching is not happening: MatchQ[x y, c_. (a : (x y))] and MatchQ[x + y, c_. (a : (x + y))] yield False and True, respectively. Using Trace doesn't help.

This has been filed as a bug.

It works without the a: pattern. MatchQ[x*y, c_. (x y)] returns True
